# Winsock - Connect to Internet through specified adapter

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming, winsock

I try to write a program using WINSOCK.
I am trying to connect to the internet from a laptop with some
network adapters ( LAN, WIRELESS,An USB ADSL Modem).
It sounds, when I call connect function, it tries to connect using
LAN, so because LAN is not connected it fails.
Here are my questions:
1)How can I force a socket to use a specified Network Adapter?
2)How can I find which adapter is connected to internet?
Thanks for reading and answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `connect()`, use [bind()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550.aspx) on the socket and specify the local IP of the desired interface.  It's fine to call `bind()` on a client socket -- just don't call `listen()`.